# Overriding html in 2 webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack

(My english is bad) I have a question about html overriding... I've 2 project : one with core, one with specific template. I am in the project with specific template, but I want to serve html files from this specific, and if the html doesn't exist, I would take the html from core... How can I do that ?
Thank's you !

I've search a lot on internet but nothing..

[Edit 1] My config

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const conf = require("./gulp.conf");
const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const WebPackAngularTranslate = require("webpack-angular-translate");
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require("lodash-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        include: [
          "node_modules/myProjectCore/src/"
        ],
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          {loader: "style-loader"},
          {loader: "css-loader", options:{sourceMap: true}},
          {loader: "resolve-url-loader", options:{sourceMap: true}},
          {loader: "sass-loader", options:{sourceMap: true}}
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          WebPackAngularTranslate.jsLoader(),
          "ng-annotate-loader",
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["es2015"]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.html$/,
        use: [
          "html-loader",
          WebPackAngularTranslate.htmlLoader()
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {loader: "url-loader", "options": {limit: 10000, mimetype: "application/font-woff"}}
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {loader: "file-loader", options: {mimetype: "application/octet-stream"}}
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: [
          {loader: "file-loader"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "myProjectCore$": getLinkToMyProjectCore()
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src("index.html")
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      _: "lodash",
      moment: "moment"
    }),
    new WebPackAngularTranslate.Plugin(),
    new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  // postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
  // debug: true,
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
    filename: "index.js"
  },
  entry: `./${conf.path.src("index")}`
};

function getLinkToMyProjectCore() {
  const defaut = "myProjectCore";
  const mode = process.argv.indexOf("--core");
  const r = (mode > -1) ? process.argv[mode + 1] : defaut;
  const result = path.join(process.cwd(), `../${r}/src`);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

It's the config of my specific project.

[Edit 2]

```
myFolder
  |- myProjectCore
  |- mySpecificProject
```

Comment: Hi Kevin. You're english is good, don't worry :) Do you have an example of the code you have at the moment you can show us? Do you have a problem or are looking for a guide on what to do?

Comment: Simply, how to ask webpack to serve html file in other project in serve mode ?

Comment: Yes :) Just one minute ^^

Comment: So, more clearly, I want (in serve mode), webpack take html both from another project and this project ^^ The another project is just beside this project